# Which is the pythonic way to decorate function depending on a condition passed through command line?

Tags: python

Let's say, I'm using the `argparse` module and I want some function to be decorated if some flag is `True` and return undecorated function if it's false.

Is it possible?
Of course I could make a couple of functions and use one of them when the flag is `True` and another when it's `False`, but it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Possible? Yes, it's possible. Pythonic? Hell, no.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Why not?

Comment: "Decorating" is just some special syntax equivalent to `func = decorator(func)`, can you just do that conditionally?

Comment: @NickT I know that, but I would like to use a decorator. Do you know how it can be done?

Comment: Could you maybe provide a short example? That could make it easier to help you or provide alternative options. In the current state it's too broad (or unclear), unfortunately.

Comment: You want to use runtime data to control operations generally performed at module load time. That makes a serious mess of things -- think of implementing test code; you want to be able to test both the decorated and undecorated versions without redefining the functions.

Comment: @Foobard your response to Nick doesn't make sense - *that is using a decorator*. So just `if flag: f = decorator(f)` where `f` has been defined already...

Comment: Now, it's less messy if you scope your function definition somewhere that's invoked at runtime rather than putting it top-level, but that's outside general practice -- it's hackery by nature.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy hm, what about having a parameterized decorator?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, and do you have the parameter lookup happening when the module is loaded, or later, after the main function is called? When the module is loaded, *you don't know what your arguments will be* yet, and you can potentially have code called many times with different arguments (consider the test suite case mentioned above).

Comment: Not saying this can't ever be reasonable. Saying I'd need to see a specific set of details where it *is* clearly reasonable (including a sane way -- "sane" ruling out inspection of globals -- to decide which set of behavior we need based on information available at call time) before helping someone do it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy right, it's not really addressing the issues you brought up.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a great approach, because the functions in a module have usually already been defined *before* any argument parsing is done.  If you want to get it working, you'll have to delay function definition until after argparse has done its thing.

The key thing that you may be overlooking here is that **decoration is done at function definition time**, i.e. it happens *once* at import.  And, generally, we put all the imports at the top of a module (the style guide also recommends this).

That doesn't mean your idea is impossible, it *is* possible, but it means you'll have to parse the command-line arguments before defining this function which may or may not be decorated.

Let's see what that actually looks like:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

def maybe_decorate(condition):
    def the_decorator(func):
        def wrapped():
            return func().upper()
        if condition:
            return wrapped
        else:
            return func
    return the_decorator


the_condition = False  # have to provide a default value for import

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--upper', action='store_true')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    the_condition = args.upper

@maybe_decorate(condition=the_condition)
def foo():
    return 'hello world'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(foo())
```

This was the cleanest I could get it, and I still have two `if __name__ == '__main__'` blocks.  That's just not a good style:

- It looks weird, any other people reading your code will likely say "[wtf](https://blog.codinghorror.com/content/images/uploads/2009/02/6a0120a85dcdae970b012877707a45970c-pi.png)".
- Will be difficult to write the tests.  To test both branches, you'll have to kick the module out of `sys.modules` and re-import it (also possible, but hacky).
- When refactoring, you may not move the function definition around within the module without altering the function's behaviour.  That violates principle of least surprise.
- If **you** come back to this code later, you too will likely say "[dude, wtf](https://blog.codinghorror.com/content/images/uploads/2009/02/6a0120a85dcdae970b012877707a45970c-pi.png)".

In summary, a conditionally-applied decorator is just not a good use-case for decorators.  The conventions of the language make this idea awkward to implement.  I recommend you abandon that approach, and think about a different design.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it's possible.  A decorator is just a function, so you can make the behavior of a decorator conditional on some variable just like anything else.  For example:

```
import argparse

flag = False


def conditional_decorator(func):
    def wrapper():
        res = func()
        if flag:
            res = res.replace('hello', 'goodbye')

        return res

    return wrapper


def parse_args():
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    p.add_argument('--flag', action='store_true')
    return p.parse_args()


@conditional_decorator
def myfunc():
    return 'hello world'


def main():
    global flag
    args = parse_args()
    flag = args.flag

    print myfunc()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Call that with flags and it prints `hello world`.  Call it with `--flag` and it prints `goodbye world`.

As other folks have said in the comments there are probably better way of accomplishing this sort of thing.

Comment: -1 I don't know why you're showing this, it's not a good idea in the first place.  Anyway, the question asked to "return *undecorated* function if it's false", not making the decorator behaviour conditional, so that's not even doing it properly anyway

Comment: I'm showing it because it's what the OP asked for.  "Not a good idea" is a matter of opinion, while this addresses the technical question. This returns the unmodified value of the function if it's false, which I think meets the original requirements. You are welcome to post an alternative.

Comment: It doesn't meet original requirements - returning unmodified value of the function is different from returning the function undecorated.  For example, this replaces the original docstring with `None` and there is one more frame in the call stack.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts.  I guess @Foobard decide if this meets their requirements or not.

Comment: Fair enough.  I posted an alternative.